# fork() behaviour different when using new lines \n

Tags: c, fork, newline

wt* is going on here?
no newlines in printf

```c
int main(){
    printf(" - main called - ");
    fork(); 
    printf(" - after fork - ");
    return 0; 
}
```

console output

```sh
     - main called -  - after fork -  - main called -  - after fork - %
```

newlines in printf

```c
int main(){
    printf(" - main called - \n");
    fork(); 
    printf(" - after fork - \n");
    return 0; 
}
```

console output

```
     - main called - 
     - after fork - 
     - after fork -
```

edit:
the solution is to use `fflush(stdout)`

```c
int main(){
    printf(" - main called - ");
    fflush(stdout);
    fork();
    printf(" - after fork - ");
    fflush(stdout);
    return(0);
}
```

console output

```
     - main called -  - after fork -  - after fork - %
```

Comment: Terminal output is line-buffered. When you fork, the child process gets a copy of the unwritten buffer.

Comment: I guess it's about output buffers, they are emptied/flushed with \n. But since they are not emptied before fork, their contents is copied to both processes. If you call fflush on stdout, you should get expected behaviour

Comment: thank you , so i wont ever use `printf` without `fflush(stdout)` for debugging ever again...